# Nonasymptotic confidence level of Bernoulli R.V.

Tags: statistics, sampling, confidence-interval, bernoulli-distribution

Let $_1,…,_$ be i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables with some unknown parameter $∈(0,1)$. Then which of the following is/are valid confidence interval(s) for $$ with **nonasymptotic** confidence level 95%?

- $(0,1)$
- $[0,\bar{X_ n}+\frac{.89}{n}]$
- $[\bar{X_ n}-1.96\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}},\bar{X_ n}+1.96\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}]$

I'm almost certain that the last one is correct since it's based on the central limit theorem (CLT) and is obtained after rearraning. Actually, the last one appears [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Normal_approximation_interval_or_Wald_interval) but apparently it's not the only correct one and I'm not sure if

$$[0,\bar{X_ n}+\frac{.89}{n}]$$

Is also correct?

It doesn't really make sense to me so if someone could explain I would really appreciate it.

Another stackexchange [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4756/confidence-interval-for-bernoulli-sampling) points out that, "if $̂ =0$ and $>30$, the 95% confidence interval is approximately $[0,3/]$ (Javanovic and Levy, 1997); the opposite holds for $̂ =1$". This [article](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2685405) costs money which I cannot afford but it made me think whether there is another approach out there to confirm the second option is also valid. Or is it none of them?

I'm a little confused but got the spirit so cheers to anyone who is willing to clear my doubts.

Comment: Your third bullet looks asymptotic, though I would expect it to use $\hat p = \bar X_n$ rather than $p$.  Your "if $\hat p =0$ ..." is the so-called [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(statistics))

Comment: It seems unlikely that $[0,\bar{X_ n}+\frac{.89}{n}]$ is a $95\%$ confidence interval - the probability of being above it seems likely to approach $\frac12$ for large sample sizes

Comment: Assuming you observe at least one success and at least one failure, $(0,1)$ is a $100\%$ confidence interval - whether this counts as a $95\%$ interval as well will depend on your definition

Comment: Thank you for your comments @Henry you're always there to save the day. Actually, you are right the third bullet seems asymptotic. For it to be a **nonasymptotic** confidence interval 95%, I would have to solve for $p$. Looks like non of them are nonasymptotic. Correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: Honestly @Henry , forget my statement about non of them being **nonasymptotic** as I confused confidence level with interval. After solving for $p$ via the CLT, i.e. $\big|\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X_ n}-p)}{p(1-p)}\big|<1.96$, the corresponding confidence interval for $$ with **nonasymptotic** confidence level 95% is $$\big[\frac{1250n\bar{X_ n}-49(\sqrt{2401-2500n(\bar{X_ n}-1)\bar{X_ n}}-49)}{1250n+4802},\frac{1250n\bar{X_ n}+49(\sqrt{2401-2500n(\bar{X_ n}-1)\bar{X_ n}}+49)}{1250n+4802}\big]$$

Comment: From here on I don't really know how to proceed because non of the options are exactly equal to this interval but I'm definitely sure it should be at least one of them. And since you said $(0,1)$ will depend on my definition, the interval in my prior comment is the reference point. Hence, do you mind lending a helping hand?  Your shared thoughts have always put me on the right track @Henry . Thanks!